# apache 2.4 module rewrite error

Tags: apache, .htaccess

trying to generate dynamic Urls using Module rewrite , it seems like m doing something wrong and getting  Server error! server encountered an internal error
 i used this code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 #Enable mod_Rewrite
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /project
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ .*/index\.(php|html?)\ HTTP
 RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.(php|html?)$ $1 [R=301,L]
 </ifModule>
```

the project is aliased to C:/project 
any pointers to achieve what m trying to?? m using apche 2.4 should the .htacess be saved         in project folder ?? or conf folder ?? 
i want to achieve something like this

```
localhost/project/index.php?departmentId=2/
localhost/project/science-d2/
```

both should load same page

Answer (score 0):

You are using an infinite loop, like this:
Suppose that your apache is configured like this in some config file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml
```

Your rewrite rule may result in:

```
/project/index.php => /project => /project/index.php => /project => ...
```

In this case, you've no need of rewrite. So the solution here is comment out all the instructions:

```
#<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# #Enable mod_Rewrite
# RewriteEngine on
# RewriteBase /project
# RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ .*/index\.(php|html?)\ HTTP
# RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.(php|html?)$ $1 [R=301,L]
#</ifModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Apache 2.4 try to replace `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` with `<IfModule rewrite_module>`

So the final code looks like this:

```
<IfModule rewrite_module>
    #Enable mod_Rewrite
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /project
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ .*/index\.(php|html?)\ HTTP
    RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.(php|html?)$ $1 [R=301,L]
</ifModule>
```

Of course make sure you comment out `rewrite_module` in .conf file so it is indeed loaded.